# Creating folders with variables in the name using PHP

Tags: php, variables

I am trying to upload a file using PHP, using an html form. in the form it asks for an album name, then in the PHP file it references, I need it to create a directory from that value of the form.

However, when I try this:

```
if (!file_exists('data/$album_name')) {
    mkdir('data/$album_name', 0777,true);
}
```

But it just creates the directory, in the `'data'` folder, of name `'$album_name'` instead of the value of `$album_name`.

I'm new to php, please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using [single quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) which prevents your variables from being interpolated. Use [double quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) instead:

```
mkdir("data/$album_name", 0777,true);
```